# Importing Word Bookmarks to Excel

Tags: excel, import, ms-word, bookmarks, vba

I am trying to import Word Bookmarks into specific Excel cells from a selected Word document. I have one macro that takes the excel data and fills it into a Word template. I need to also be able to take that word document and import it back into Excel. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Import()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim nextRow As Range

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files,*.doc;*.docx", , _
"Browse for document") 'dialog box
    If wdFileName = False Then
        MsgBox "No File Selected."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set wdDoc = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        wdDoc.Visible = True
            On Error Resume Next
        wdDoc.Documents.Open Filename:=wdFileName
            On Error GoTo 0
        wdDoc.Documents(wdFileName).Activate
            On Error GoTo 0
    End If


With wdDoc 'start import

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set nextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

ws.Range("H" & (nextRow.Row)).Value2 = wdDoc.Bookmarks("Bookmark1").Range.Value2

End With
wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

I'm getting "Run-Time:438 / Object doesn't support this property or method" on the line "ws.Range("H" & (nextRow.Row)).Value2 = wdDoc.Bookmarks("Named_Insured").Range.Value2"

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: In the VBA window, click on "Tools" then "References" and make sure that there is a checkbox next to "Microsoft Word xx.0 Object Library"

Step 2: Change the problem line to-

```
ws.Range("H" & (nextRow.Row)).Value = _
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Name_Insured").Range.Text
```

Step 3: Change the last line to-

```
ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had it as .text (for both ws.range and wddoc.bookmarks) before, it still was giving me the same error. The bookmark is a selection, or at least should be.

Comment: Try: ws.Range("H" & (nextRow.Row)).Value = wdDoc.Bookmarks("Named_Insured").Range.Text

Comment: I think the issue you're having is that the first section needs to be written for Excel (which typically uses .Value) and the second portion needs to be written for Word (which doesn't use .Value at all)

Comment: Originally that's how I had it (I just reversed the export code). I've gone through just about every combination since then and every time I hit this wall.

Comment: Just edited my answer after troubleshooting and testing on my own.  Your wdDoc object wasn't working quite right--basically just switch it out for ActiveDocument and the code should work just fine.

Comment: This edit seems to be the right path to go, however, it's telling me no activate document is set and breaking on the same line. Did you call/open the document in another way?

Comment: Got it, for anyone else in the future looking for answers I changed the 

`set wdDoc = Createobject` 

and everything after it to 

`Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(Filename:=wdFileName)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use Bookmarks, like this.

```
Sub PushToWord()

Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim bkmk As Word.Bookmark
sWdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , False)
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(sWdFileName)
On Error Resume Next

    ActiveDocument.Variables("BrokerFirstName").Value = Range("B1").Value
    ActiveDocument.Variables("BrokerLastName").Value = Range("B2").Value
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

On Error Resume Next
objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Or, use DocVariables, as such.

```
Sub PushToWord()

Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim bkmk As Word.Bookmark
sWdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , False)
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(sWdFileName)
'On Error Resume Next

objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("BrokerFirstName").Value = Range("BrokerFirstName").Value
objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("BrokerLastName").Value = Range("BrokerLastName").Value
objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("Ryan").Value = Range("Ryan").Value


objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

'On Error Resume Next
objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

BTW, you run these code samples from Excel, not from Word.